# Inserting different component in JTable

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable

I am trying to make something like

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DixBL.png]

I am using JTable for this but am unable to figure out how to add those `Libraries`, `Tools`, `Examples` rows.
I would like to keep the rows in one table if possible(because then i would have to write code so that only one row is selected from all the tables combined).
I would prefer if someone gives a solution using JTable only though if this can be accomplished using any other component i would be very willing to use it.

Comment: *"I would prefer if someone gives a solution using JTable only"*  <DWS>Would you like coffee and a donut with that?</DWS>  SO is not a code generation machine.

Comment: I wrote that because this component was actually a part of a JTabbedPane and the other panes contain a JTable only so it would be more cleaner if this could be solved using JTable only and I also wrote that i am open to other options.

Comment: *"..i am open to other options."*  Here's an option.  Try something and show your efforts in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.  And stop asking for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unable to figure out how to add those Libraries, Tools, Examples rows.

They just look like rows of data that only contain data in the second column.

If you want to highlight the rows with a special Border then you could use the approach described in [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which overrides the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of JTable set the Border of all columns of a given row.